# Kibana not working after removing shield plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-shield

I've been testing out the Shield plugin for elasticsearch and kibana to provide security. I installed the kibana plugin and quickly realized that I can't use it until I set up SSL stuff. For nowI would like to use the basic browser authentication that was present before installing the plugin to kibana. I did this:

```
bin/kibana plugin --remove shield
```

and restarted kibana but now it fails to run, giving me the following error:

```
FATAL { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/opt/kibana/optimize/bundles/sense.entry.js']
  cause:
   { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/opt/kibana/optimize/bundles/sense.entry.js']
     errno: -13,
     code: 'EACCES',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/opt/kibana/optimize/bundles/sense.entry.js' },
  isOperational: true,
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/opt/kibana/optimize/bundles/sense.entry.js' }
```

I checked that there weren't any settings in kibana.yml that might be causing this, and even with any settings I had added after installing the plugin commented out, I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a permissions issue. Check if the owner is 'kibana' and permissions are 644.

`cd /opt/kibana/optimize/bundles
 ls -l`

If any of these are missing, do the following:

`sudo chown kibana:kibana sense.entry.js
 sudo chmod 644 sense.entry.js`

Do the same with any other files the log informs you of. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, the kibana user needed write privilege to that and a few other files and didn't have it.